# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined. Jquery already attached

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just got an error and I do not know why it is happening. Below are my functions.

```
function senditnow(){
 //something  
}

$('.check-with-bank').click(function(){
  //something
   checksuccess_checkall(successsent);
   if(successsent == true) {
       //It already passed and come to this function but It cannot call.
        senditnow();
   }
}
```

I also attached jQuery and all other features working well except stopping at `senditnow()` function.

Can you help me to explain why?

Comment: What's `checksuccess_checkall`? If you think its code is relevant to this question, please post that code too if possible.

Comment: Also, I don't see `successsent` never being declared.

Comment: Hi. As I commented out in the code above. All code passed to that function but it stops calling that function in debugging of Chrome

Comment: returning `true` from `checksuccess_checkall()` will not set `successsent` to `true`. I'm guessing all you need is `if (checksuccess_checkall()) senditnow();`

Comment: Hi @ChrisG. Thank you for your suggestion. I will test again with your method.

Comment: well how is `senditnow` defined? where is it actually declared? My guess is something on how it is defined is the issue and not with the code shown.

Comment: @epascarello because the code is so long and it is ajax so I cannot paste all here.   Thank you for your suggestion. I am checking again.

Comment: @MinhAnh Is `senditnow();` the line that throws the error? If so, the function is out of scope. If so, we need to see more code.

Comment: @ChrisG: Hi Since I inserted alert function before senditnow function. It still show my alert msg but calling senditnow function not defined. As you said, it is out of scope.

Comment: Like is `senditnow` inside something like a different document.ready block? My guess is yes.... If it is defined on the page like you said, and it is not available with the block scope and it is not in the window scope so you can not find it. With the information provided, it is really hard to actually help you. As the way it is written it sort of should work minus the really weird thing you have going on with `successsent`

Comment: hi @epascarello. I found the solution. As I upgraded to Jquery 3 and over, problem solved :(

Answer (score 2):

the problem may be that `successsent` value is not changing, as far as i know pass by reference only works on arrays an objects, so it would be better if you do

```
successsent = checksuccess_checkall();
```

if `checksuccess_checkall()` returns a boolean, that way you can validate if `successsent` is true, and you should check what values `successsent` has before and after calling `checksuccess_checkall()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I am checking again